# Store binded object before change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, data-binding

I have an object which contains information on a group:

```
selectedGroup:  { 
      name: Test Group,
      id: 10,
      description: a group,
      owner: 88,
      ownerIsUser: False
 }
```

I have textbox which binds to the selectedGroups.name property. I need to store that name in it's own variable before a change occurs.

I have an AJAX library that allows me to update the groups info like name and description but it needs the old name to identify which group to update. I tried:

```
var oldName = selectedGroup.name
```

But this doesn't work since as soon as I start typing something oldName gets updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch):

```
$scope.$watch('selectedGroup.name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // save/copy oldVal somewhere 
});
```

PD: To deep copy the object you can use  [`angular.copy()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)

Comment: I'm trying the deep copy right now. From what I recall watch will update on every change. If I'm changing a users name the old copy will simply be the the new copy minus 1 letter right?